# Where can I watch Digimon Adventure Tri. in English online?

Tags: digimon-tri

Does anyone know where I could watch Digimon Adventure Tri. in English? Every version I find is in Japanese.

Comment: English as in what? subtitles or dubs (voices)?

Comment: dubs not really looking for subtitles!

Answer (score 2):

No such edition exists presently - there were dub screenings but the license for those had lapsed prior - but Shout! Factory [has acquired home distribution rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_tri.#English-language_version) for the media, and plan do to a dual-language release in the future.

In the meantime, the subbed versions available on Crunchyroll are actually quite well done.  They're also [available for free](http://www.crunchyroll.com/digimon-adventure-tri), and I'd encourage you to enjoy it while it's still available on the site.